# Parallel version branches that must be synced and integrated to trunk

Tags: svn

I need to begin a branch (beta) based in another branch (alpha), you can see this as a beta version based in an alpha version. This two branches will end merged with trunk, first the alpha branch and then the beta branch.

Option 1: Create alpha branch from trunk and then create beta branch from alpha. Beta will be updated with changesets from alpha periodically because beta must contain all functionality from alpha (points 1 and 2).

```
               /----beta---/(1)---/(2)-----beta-------\
              /           /      /                     \
     /------------alpha--/------/---\                   \
    /                                \                   \
------------trunk---------------------------------------------->
```

Option 2: Create alpha from trunk and then beta from trunk too. Update beta with the changes of alpha to put both with the same functionality (point 3). After this beta will be updated with changesets from alpha periodically because beta must contain all functionality from alpha (points 4 and 5).

```
               /--/(3)--beta----/(4)--/(5)----beta-----\
              /  /             /     /                  \
     /-------o--/--alpha------/-----/---\                \
    /       /                            \                \
----------------trunk------------------------------------------->
```

Both branches will be merged back to trunk.

Which is the better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1, because it eliminates unnecessary in this case merge from alpha to beta at start and physical path correlate to logical

Comment: Will not give problems when integrating "beta" with trunk because "beta" starts from "alpha" instead of "trunk"?

Comment: Will not give *any* problem on *any* re-integration path - because SVN will detects changes between leafs, history have (almost) zero-value for this job

Comment: So SVN will do the merge just _ignoring_ the ancestry, like applying a patch.

I'm still concerned about the conflicts that may appear when merging "beta" over trunk because merging "alpha" over trunk before. SVN deals with this?

Comment: SVN will use **common ancestor** as referencepoint for two revision. Pre-applied patches detected and not applied again (at least in my different merges with CI)